# Why does absolute positionining within <button> works differently from <div>

Tags: html, css, css-position

I expect following code to put my span to the top-left corner of the button, but it doesn't. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button style='height:100px;width:100px;position:relative;'>
            <span style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;'>text</span>
        </button>    
    </body>
</html>
```

`<span>` is placed relative to the vertical-**middle** line (with 3px padding I can't explain).

Replacing `<button>` with `<div>` **does** places `<span>` at the top-left corner.

**Question:** why does absolute positioning within button (with position:relative) behaves differently from layout using `<div>`? And how do I fix it?

Background: I use two absolutely positioned div's within button to create a floating-width button with rounded corners.

**EDIT:** **IMPORTANT** IE 8.0 works exactly as I expect it (span in the top-left corner), the problem I see is in Firefox (3.6.6).

Comment: Fascinating... I thought it was due to `margin`/`padding`, but that does not seem to be the case...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a function of the snippet above, but are you missing a doctype in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, the actual page does have the doctype (added to the question).

Comment: As an interesting note, `top:-50%` will position it where you want.

Comment: Yes it will (or 51%, since 50% might leave a line up top). But I want to avoid having to have separate sections for firefox and IE. For now I'm using <a> tag disguised as buttons.

Comment: It would be interesting to see whether Chrome and Safari followed IE or FF. If the former it suggests a problem in FF (which you could fix for them!), if the latter it suggests the behaviour is the standard and IE is deviating again (rightly or wrongly).

Comment: both Chrome and Safari align div to the left-top corner of the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advice against using a `<button>` this way. It is really difficult to style and you'll end up having to write specific styles for different browsers. 
I needed to achieve something very similar and after dealing with a large amount of exceptions and fiddly positioning to accommodate different browser rendering, I went for this structure instead:

```
<div class="button">
 <span>
  <button>Text</button>
 </span>
</div>
```

With the button tag reset this way:

```
button {
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border:0 none;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    font-weight:inherit;
    margin:0;
    overflow:visible;
    padding:0;
   position:relative;
 }
```

You can even use js to wrap the `<button>` on page load. This system has turned out to be much more solid and reliable. Requiring less css and almost no browser specific styling.

Update:
As I commented below, the wrapping element should not be an `<a>` tag. Remember that we need the `<button>` to keeps its functionality, we just need it to be text only (form will still submit on enter). 
You can still re-use any css that you may be using to turn standard links into expandable button widgets only in this case it;s a `<div>` instead of an `<a>`.

Comment: I end up using <a..> tag for that, so that I can use href attribute in place of button's/submit `name` attribute, and use jQuery to turn all those <a class='button'...> into button widgets. How do you handle enter-click on forms? is there a jQuery plugin for that?

Comment: You can't wrap an <a> around a <button>. If we were to make a plain <a> into an expandable button widget, you just add the span inside and apply the css for that. 
But because it is a <button> we are dealing with, you need to stick with the <div>. Remember that we are not removing the <button> tag, so the form will still submit on enter, as well as when clicking on the button (depending on the dimensions of the button widget you may need some css tweaking to make sure that the clickable areas is wide enough)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is only with Firefox?? (3.6.6) - Can't fix it with standard CSS.  Try:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { 
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

That will do it for Firefox hopefully.  Good luck!