# Abs. positioned element inside Button is not positioned correctly

Tags: html, css, button, firefox4

I'm trying to put an icon inside a button element and I'm getting strange positioning but in Firefox 4. Check out this demo http://jsfiddle.net/j6q2e/3/

It works as expected in Chrome and IE but in Firefox the icon is completely off the reservation. Is that a known bug? Is there a way to fix that?

(I don't want to use `<a>` because it's a submit button for a form and I want to keep it that way. I also would like to avoid using background-image style because the icon is in a CSS sprite image and to use as background-image I'd have to save it as a separate PNG.)

Comment: i'm sure you noticed this and that it doesn't necessarily help, but if you set the button's `padding` to `0` it works. crazy problem.

Comment: @newtron You can also set the margin on the #icon to `margin: -4px 18px;` to get it to work in FF.  Of course, that screws up IE :)  Looks like the problem is that IE takes the offset before the padding, and FF takes the offset from the padding.

Comment: Looks like it's a long standing FF bug, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213664/why-does-absolute-positionining-within-button-works-differently-from-div

Comment: @james6848 Thanks, I didn't see this thread when I initially searched on the topic. It really sucks but I guess I'll have to use a workaround. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick update to get this thing "answered"...

So yeah, this is a bug in Firefox, and still is as of version 5. Chrome, IE9 and Opera all correctly position the icon inside the button.

There is another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213664/why-does-absolute-positionining-within-button-works-differently-from-div) dealing with it and here's [the Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=437722).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to keep it as a sprite and use it as a background image, just adjust the space around that image to allow for the size of your button. You might want to also consider [diagonal sprites](http://www.aaronbarker.net/2010/07/diagonal-sprites/) to help solve your problem.